# What is the best way to implement buttons inside a gridview?

Tags: xaml, gridview, data-binding, uwp, c++-cx

This is in C++/CX and XAML for the UWP. Let's say I have a class:

```
public ref class foo
{
  private:
   String^ title;
   String^ printstring;
 public:
  foo()
  {
     title = "this is my title";
     printstring = "test";
  }
  property String^ Title
  {
     String^ get()
     {
        return title;
     }
  }

}
```

I have a vector `Platform::Collections::Vector<foo^>^ testbind`. I also have a property that returns that vector. In my XAML, I have a gridview, with the ItemSource set to the property for `testbind` and the ItemTemplate set to this:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:foo">
    <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title} TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
        <Button x:Name=button/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

How do I make it so when I click the button, I can do something with `printstring` in code behind? In this hypothetical scenario, all of the Titles and printstrings are the same, but in my actual project, they will be different for each member of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using c++ but I think your problem is more xaml related so I'll try to answer that.

When using DataTemplates there is always the problem that you can't use named elements (without going to great lengths to find them by traversing the visual tree). Your solution here is Binding.

Disclaimer: this is browser code

```
 <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:foo">
        <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title} TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
            <Button x:Name=button Command={x:Bind MyCommand, CommandParameter={x:Bind Title}}/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then pick up the parameter and execute your logic. 
I hope this solves your problem.